# How does OpenCV Manager work?

Tags: android, opencv, android-service, aidl

This problem is confusing me. I know the app, which is made by myself using opencv sdk, must call the functions in OpenCV Manager. But how do they call each other? My idea is using aidl. So I tried to make a aidl demo to simulate this mode. 
I made a server and a client. The server started a service first, and the client called the methods from server service. This works! But I found that the OpenCV Manager had not to run, while the app called its methods. So I made some improvements in client app.

1. check if the server app is running, if not, start it.
2. start the service in server app.
3. call methods in server service.

And there is a problem in **step 1**. If I use `startActivity(intent)`to start the server app, it will bring to the front of my client app, which is not what I want.
Could anyone tell me if my thinking is right or how to run another app in an app silently? Thanks.

Comment: I'm wondering about this too. Did you get any further on this? I was thinking that it would communicate over TCP/UDP over localhost.

Comment: I found an app whose structure is somehow like OpenCV Manager, so I raised this question. And through its code, I confirm that it is via AIDL which OpenCV Manager probably uses. Then using intent to start service directly(not have to start activity). @Kaj Toet

Comment: Okay, thanks! I see there is no equivalent on iOS unfortunately.